# Enable button only if text is filled in (NO SPACES)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked around for an answer to my question, but all the solutions I have found do not take into account that spaces also work as input.

I have a join function, and the button shouldn't be enabled if a user only enters space. It should need actual text. Anyone has a solution to this?

Here's my function:

```
$("#join").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name != "") {
            socket.emit("join", name);
            $("#login").detach();
            $("#UsersOnline").show();
            $("#msg").show();
            $("#messaging").show();
            $("#msg").focus();
            ready = true;
        }
```

Comment: You can try to replace all the whitespaces ```$("#name").val().replace(/\s/g,"")```, and if what is left is an empty string is because there is not actual text.

Comment: `if (name.trim() != "")` or `if (name.trim().length)`, though this approach allows white-space between characters in the `name` string, but removes leading and trailing white-space characters. Do remember that your user knows their name, and will be frequently annoyed by an overzealous regular expression that tells them that their name is invalid; see the story of [Mr. Null](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/) (at Wired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use jquery trim()

```
var name = $.trim($("#name").val());
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

EDIT:

As @David Thomas pointed out, we can also use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

```
var name = $("#name").val().trim();
```

```js
function updateResult() {
  var before = $("#name").val().replace(/\s/g,'SPACE');
  var name = $("#name").val().trim();

   $('#result').text('Before:' + before + "\nAfter:" + name);

}

$(document).ready(function(){

  updateResult();

  $('body').on('keyup','#name',function(){
  
    updateResult();
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>By default value i left left a space for the name</p>
Name : <input type="text" id="name" value=" "><br>
<br>
Value of name : <pre id="result">empty</pre>
```

Comment: While jQuery is an option, why invoke jQuery to emulate [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)?

Comment: you are quite right, i guess I have over indulged myself in jQuery rendering me pretty green to vanilla javascript. I shall update my answer

Comment: Wouldn't I need an if-function to make sure that the button does not work unless there is text filled in?

Comment: yes, sorry example code was demonstrating how .trim() worked. Try your code with `if (name.trim() != "") {` as the if statement.

Comment: Ahh ok.. Works great! Thanks again